# Python text file data extraction

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks likes this

```
P1 : Some data
P2 : blabla
P4 : whatever
F1 : something
F2 : something else
G6 : This entry continues
G6 : down here
```

This is followed by a empty line and then a new record which looks the same as above (about 100k total). I need to get a text file in which every line contains the P2, p4 and G6 entry separated by a tab.

This is what I have so far

```
output = open('out.txt', 'w')
output.write("P1\tG6\n")

P1_ = False
G6_ = False

with open("data.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('P1 :'):
            P1 = line[4:10]
            P1_ = True

        elif line.startswith('G6'):         
            G6 = line.lstrip('G6 :')
            G6_ = True

        else:
            continue

        if P1_ and G6_ :
            output.write(year + "\t" + abstract)
            year_ = False
            abstract_ = False
output.close()
data.close()
```

The problem I encounter is that some records do not have all entries I need and some have the G6 spread over several lines. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: After reading all of your answers I realised my question was a bit vague. I do need the records which do not have all entries.

Comment: Just an idea. You should use a dict maybe to aggregate your lines. Then it will be easier to recombine. The following step would help: parse your file using a dictionary where the keys are your codes. Then recombine as you wish. I Hope this will help

Comment: Using a `dict` will be a good idea as a @Kursion said.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output you want?

Comment: What you did below is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, you could create a dictionary for each data chunk.  When you hit blank lines write to your output file and clear the dictionary. Using a `defaultdict` makes concatenating the multiple entries per key easier.

```
from collections import defaultdict

keep = ['P2', 'P4', 'G6']
tmp_dict = defaultdict(str)

# a function to handle formatting of output
def output_format(the_dict):
    return '\t'.join([the_dict[k].rstrip() for k in keep]) + '\n'

with open('test.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:

        # if there's non-whitespace text on this line
        if line.strip():
            k, v = line.split(' : ')

            # store the data if the key is relevant,
            # appending if the key has already been hit
            if k in keep:
                tmp_dict[k] += v.rstrip() + ' '

        # when there's a blank line, write the data to
        # the output file and clear the temporary dict
        else:
            outfile.write(output_format(tmp_dict))
            tmp_dict = defaultdict(str)

    # one last time, in case file doesn't end in newline
    outfile.write(output_format(tmp_dict))
```

Not sure I fully understand the desired output. This prints the value for P2, then for P4 then for G6 all on one line with a tab between each. For example:

```
blabla  whatever    This entry continues down here
```

If an element is missing, the tabs will still be printed, so if P4 is missing there will be two tabs in a row.

But the output is flexible. If you wanted, say, to preserve the original format after filtering and merging G6, then you could use:

```
def output_format(the_dict):

    output = ''
    for k, v in the_dict.iteritems():
        output += '{} : {}\n'.format(k, the_dict[k])

    return output + '\n'
```

Comment: this is very clean! Like it a lot. Just want to mention that the OP indicated he desires an output record ONLY when there's a P1 record and at least one G6 record in a given block. I also acknowledge that I'm not 100% clear on exactly what the right conditions are as the problem description and the sample code don't quite match. See my answer below...

Comment: wait really? I don't see that but maybe I'm spacing out here.  Also I think I have the output wrong, tweaking it now...

Comment: I got tripped up on this as well - OP wrote at very bottom of post: "The problem I encounter is that some records do not have all entries I need and some have the G6 spread over several lines. Any ideas on how to do this?"

Comment: I took this to mean that sometimes an element (e.g. P4) is missing, but that the code should deal with this gracefully. Not sure how to handle output for that.

Comment: Yep. I sort of inferred from his code snippet that s/he explicitly required the P1_ and G6_ boo leans to be true before outputting to the text file. Anyhow, I think your code is about as close as anyone will get. Up voting now! Well done!

Comment: @Jasper33 I was a bit vague indeed, but i need all the records even if they do not have all entries.

Answer (score 0):

So I added a new variable `G6_Done` that keeps track of when we've started seeing G6 which prevents entering the bottom if (which writes to the file) till we're no longer seeing G6 (as then `G6_Done == True`). Then, by using `G6 = ""` in its definition, we can write to it continuously till we reset things.

```
output = open('out.txt', 'w')
output.write("P1\tG6\n")

P1_ = False
G6_ = False
G6_Done = False
G6 = ""
with open("data.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('P1 :'):
            P1 = line[4:10]
            P1_ = True

        elif line.startswith('G6'):
            G6 += line.lstrip('G6 :')
            G6_Done = False
            G6_ = True
        elif G6 and not G6_Done:
            G6 = True
        else:
            continue

        if P1_ and G6_ and G6_Done:
            output.write(year + "\t" + abstract)
            year_ = False
            abstract_ = False
            G6 = ""
            P1_ = False
            G6_ = False
            G6_Done = False
output.close()
data.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is parsing, I suppose.

I hope you can somehow logically detect when a new record starts, even if some lines are missing. I suppose that the order of the entries is fixed, so you can detect when one group is over and the next starts by the fact that e.g. P fields always go before G fields.

This code works reasonably and handles the missing fields:

```
FIELD_ORDER = ['P1', 'P2', 'P4', 'F1', 'F2', 'G6']


class RecordReader(object):
  def __init__(self, input_stream):
    self.input_stream = input_stream
    self.prev_record = None

  def readNext(self):
    if self.prev_record:
      # if we have a value pushed back, return it first
      prev_value = self.prev_record
      self.prev_record = None
      return prev_value
    # read things for real
    line = self.input_stream.readline()
    if line == '':
      return None  # end of file
    tag, value = line.split(':')  # assume the format is always correct
    return tag.strip(), value.strip()

  def pushBack(self, record):
    self.prev_record = record


def readGroup(reader):
  data = {}  # accumulate values here
  expected = FIELD_ORDER[:] # make a copy, for we'll change the expectations
  while True:
    record = reader.readNext()
    if not record:
      return data # end of file, we are done
    tag, content = record
    # are we still in the same group?
    if tag in expected:
      if tag == 'G6':
        # append to existing G6, if any
        data[tag] = data.get(tag, '') + ' ' + content
      else:
        data[tag] = content
      # cut away all the expected fields up to the field we just found
      point = expected.index(tag)
      if tag != 'G6':
        point += 1 # stop expecting the tag we just found (unless it's G6)
      expected = expected[point:]
    else:
      reader.pushBack(record) # it belongs to next group
      return data


def read(input_stream):
  reader = RecordReader(input_stream)
  while True:
    group = readGroup(reader)
    if group:
      p1 = group.get('P1', 'No P1 found')
      g6 = group.get('G6', 'No G6 found')
      print "%s\t%s" % (p1, g6)  # edit to taste
    else:
      # we could only get an empty group at end of file.
      break

def main():
  with open('foo.bar') as input_stream:
    read(input_stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

@blackcloud, following @Kursian's original comment, I think the dictionary approach is the cleanest.  Here's some sample code based on what *i think* you are after:

```
f_in  = open('data.txt','r')
f_out = open('out.txt', 'w')
f_out.write("P1\tG6\n")

myDict = {}
for line in f_in:                                     #loop through each line     in the input text file...
  if not len(line.strip()):                           #check for a blank line - your "record separator"...
    if 'P1' in myDict and 'G6' in myDict:             #check if this record meets your conditions
      abstract = myDict['P1']+'\t'+myDict['G6']+'\n'  #build your tab-separated abstract
      f_out.write(abstract)                           #and write a record if so
    myDict = {}                                       #reset your dictionary for your next "record"
  else:                                               #otherwise,
    key,val = line.split(' : ')                       #split the line into its key and value components
    if key == 'P1':                                   #if it has a P1
      myDict[key] = val.strip()                       #add it...
    if key == 'G6':                                   #if it has a G6
      if 'G6' in myDict:                              #check if it's already in the dictionary
        myDict[key] += ''.join([' ',val.strip()])     #and just append to the existing value with a space
      else:                                           #otherwise
        myDict[key] = val.strip()                     #just add the G6 key,value pair

f_out.close()
f_in.close()                                          #cleanup!
```

If I understand your original challenge, you are looking for blocks of data separated by a `blank line` and having at least one `P1` entry and one or more `G6` lines.  So, extending your example, given an input text file like this:

```
P1 : Some data
P2 : blabla
P4 : whatever
F1 : something
F2 : something else
G6 : This entry continues
G6 : down here

P1 : Some data
P2 : blabla
P4 : whatever
G6 : This entry continues
F1 : something
F2 : something else
G6 : down here

P2 : blabla
P4 : whatever
F1 : something
F2 : something else
G6 : This entry continues
G6 : down here

P1 : Some data
P2 : blabla
P4 : whatever
F1 : something
G6 : This entry continues
F2 : something else
```

You'll end up with an output file that looks like this after running the above script:

```
P1  G6
Some data   This entry continues down here
Some data   This entry continues down here
Some data   This entry continues
```

Hope this all helps and big thanks to all the contributors here!!